# Fetch data from Room with Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Hi guys I cannot fetch data from my database:

I have in my DAO:

```
   @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ClientEntity")
    fun getClients(): Flow<List<ClientEntity>>
```

RepoImpl:

```
 override suspend fun getClients(): Flow<List<ClientEntity>> {
        return clientDao.getClients()
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
fun getClients(): Flow<List<Client>> = flow {
        val clients = mutableListOf<Client>()
        clientsRepository.getClients().collect { clientEntities ->
            clients.addAll(clientEntities.map { it.toClient() })
        }
        emit(clients)
    }
```

Screen:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = myContext) {  
            viewModel.getClients().collect{
                val clients = viewModel.getClients()
                Log.d(TAG, "ClientsListScreen: da $clients")
            }
        
    }
```

Im using jetpack compose, with this code I dont see logd in my Screen.
I know that are clients in my database since I inspected it.

Comment: put log in your viewmodel and also put try catch block to check is there any exception or not

Comment: `getClients()` should not be a suspend function. You don't need to suspend to fetch a Flow, so this just prevents you from conveniently getting Flow references in property initializers. If you fix that, your `getClients()` function (which really should be a property according to Kotlin convention) could just be a one-liner with a `map` call. You should not be using a LaunchedEffect to read from your Flow. You should be converting it to State and using the state value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove suspend keyword of `getClients()` from everywhere

You can also improve your `View Model` code like this

```
private val _clientResponse: MutableState<ClientState> = mutableStateOf(WeatherState())
    val clientResponse: State<ClientState> = _clientResponse


viewModelScope.launch {
                repository.getClients()
                    .onStart {
                         _clientResponse.value = ClientState(
                    isLoading =  true
                )
                    }.catch {
                         _clientResponse.value = ClientState(
                    error = it.message ?: "Something went wrong"
                )
                    }.collect{
                         _clientResponse.value = ClientState(
                    data = it
                )
                    }
            }


data class ClientState(
    val data: List< ClientEntity > = emptyList(),
    val error: String = "",
    val isLoading: Boolean = false
)
```

**In Composable function**

```
val clientResponse = viewModel.clientResponse.value

if (clientResponse.data.isNotEmpty())
 // do something

if (clientResponse.error.isNotEmpty)
// do something

if(clientResponse.isLoading)
// do something
```

Comment: This can be simplified more by using `stateIn` instead of having to create a backing `MutableStateFlow` property and separately having to collect and re-emit values from the source flow.

Comment: Actually, I mean `collectAsState`, not `stateIn`, since we're using State, not a StateFlow.